# Twitter Bootstrap carousel component controls positioning glitch in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I redesigned a website for a friend using twitter bootstrap which i supposed would save me from thinking about cross-browser compatibility.

Now I try to use it with firefox only to notice that the controls of the Carousel component move away when you hover them, thus making it impossible to click them. Not to mention it looks rather unprofessional.

The strange behavior can be seen here and occurs to me on Firefox 18.0.2:
http://snow-first.com/snow-rabbit-3/

Anybody has a clue to what's going on? Tried looking in the css but the only thing that should happen on hover is an opacity change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the selectors `.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus` (line 576 of your CSS) add `position:absolute`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! Seems rather strange that firefox removes the `position: abolute;` that `.carousel-control` already has on hover though..

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin a `position:relative` overide it, that's why. If the answer is correct you can accept it.